# Spring boot: Read a file PATH from "application.properties"

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties

I'm using Spring Boot and I want to read a file path from the resources/application.properties file and set its value to a String in a Java class:

**resources/application.properties**

```
mypath=dir/file.ext
```

**resources/application-context.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

**MyJavaClass.java**

```
@Component
public class MyJavaClass{ 

    @Value("${mypath}") 
    String mypath;

    public void printme(){
        System.err.println(mypath);
    }
}
```

When I try to print the String, it always prints "null". What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. I was trying to use the value annotation from the "main" thread (the one that executes code from the main function).

If I get the values from the code of the services for example, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Is the resource folder in the class path? If not try like this

```
<bean id="propertyLoader" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I assume like your property file is present in the same location as the configuration file from which it is referring.

Comment: Yes, the resources folder is in the classpath.